# Connecting django signal handlers in tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, caching, signals

Using django-cacheops, I want to test that my views are getting cached as I intend them to be. In my test case I'm connecting cacheops `cache_read` signal to a handler that should increment a value in the cache for hits or misses. However, the signal is never fired. Does anyone know the correct way to connect a django signal handler in a testcase, purely for use in that testcase?

here's what I have so far

```
from cacheops.signals import cache_read

cache.set('test_cache_hits', 0)
cache.set('test_cache_misses', 0)

def cache_log(sender, func, hit, **kwargs):
    # never called
    if hit:
        cache.incr('test_cache_hits')
    else:
        cache.incr('test_cache_misses')


class BootstrapTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(BootstrapTests, cls).setUpClass()
        cache_read.connect(cache_log)
        assert cache_read.has_listeners()

    def test_something_that_should_fill_and_retrieve_cache(self):
        ....
        hits = cache.get('test_cache_hits') # always 0
```

I've also tried connecting the signal handler at the module level, and in the regular testcase `setUp` method, all with the same result.

EDIT: 
Here's my actual test code, plus the object I'm testing. I'm using the `cached_as` decorator to cache a function. This test is currently failing.

boostrap.py

```
class BootstrapData(object):

    def __init__(self, app, person=None):
        self.app = app

    def get_homepage_dict(self, context={}):

        url_name = self.app.url_name

        @cached_as(App.objects.filter(url_name=url_name), extra=context)
        def _get_homepage_dict():
            if self.app.homepage is None:
                return None

            concrete_module_class = MODULE_MAPPING[self.app.homepage.type]
            serializer_class_name = f'{concrete_module_class.__name__}Serializer'
            serializer_class = getattr(api.serializers, serializer_class_name)
            concrete_module = concrete_module_class.objects.get(module=self.app.homepage)
            serializer = serializer_class(context=context)
            key = concrete_module_class.__name__
            return {
                key: serializer.to_representation(instance=concrete_module)
            }
        return _get_homepage_dict()
```

test_bootstrap.py

```
class BootstrapDataTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(BootstrapDataTest, self).setUp()

        def set_signal(signal=None, **kwargs):
            self.signal_calls.append(kwargs)
        self.signal_calls = []
        cache_read.connect(set_signal, dispatch_uid=1, weak=False)
        self.app = self.setup_basic_app() # creates an 'App' model and saves it

    def tearDown(self):
        cache_read.disconnect(dispatch_uid=1)

    def test_boostrap_data_is_cached(self):

        obj = BootstrapData(self.app)
        obj.get_homepage_dict()

        # fails, self.signal_calls == []
        self.assertEqual(self.signal_calls, [{'sender': App, 'func': None, 'hit': False }])

        self.signal_calls = []

        obj.get_homepage_dict()
        self.assertEqual(self.signal_calls, [{'sender': App, 'func': None, 'hit': True}])
```

Comment: Are you sure that the tests will trigger the `cache_read` signal?  Not just any cache read will trigger cacheops `cache_read` signal. https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/master/cacheops/query.py

Also in the cachops package they have an example of a test where they connect a signal in the `setUp` method. https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/blob/daa907d6ec5dc98d5cc80a3d519469fb134bd0bb/tests/tests.py#L917

Comment: I could be wrong but django-cacheops is designed to cache querysets and not regular keys. Hence, the `cache_read` signal will not be called since the value you are trying to get is not a queryset.

Comment: You probably don't make cacheops requests or never get hits. You should supply your test code.

Comment: thanks ARJMP - that test code looks like a good avenue to try. @Suor - I'm just doing regular saves and retrieves on models that are registered for cacheops. When manually testing this it's fairly clear that cacheops is caching them but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, it turned out to be that my test cases subclassed django rest framework's APITestCase, which in turn subclasses django's SimpleTestCase.

looking in the cacheops sources, I found that those tests subclass TransactionTestCase, and switching out the test case fixed this issue.

Would be interested to know why this is the case but the issue is solved for now.

Comment: This is because `SimpleTestCase` wraps each test into a transaction and cacheops turns itself off in a transaction once it's dirty. This is because db state visible from within transaction is different and should not be cached nor rely on cache.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why this is happening but I will try to make a useful answer anyway.

First, if you want to test whether cache works you shouldn't rely on its own side effects to check that, and signals are side effects of its primary function - preventing db calls. Try testing that:

```
def test_it_works(self):
    with self.assertNumQueries(1):
        obj.get_homepage_dict()

    with self.assertNumQueries(0):
        obj.get_homepage_dict()
```

Second, if you want to know what's going on you may dig in adding prints everywhere including cacheops code and see where it stops. Alternatively, you can make a test for me to see, the instruction is here https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops#writing-a-test.

Last, your test is a bit wrong. For `@cached_as()` sender would be `None` and func would be decorated function.

Comment: Thanks for the help - coming back to this many months later, I've learned that it was because my test cases didn't use TransactionTestCase as their base ( as with the tests in cacheops ). Switching the testcase base class makes it all work.